# Rmarkdown won't knit to HTML xcrun: error on mac

Tags: r, macos, r-markdown, xcrun

I recently switched from a pc to a macbook (running big sur 11.0.1) and just installed R studios yesterday. I'm working in R and I get this error when I try to knit to an HTML:

```
xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
Quitting from lines 15-18 (thesis_analyses.Rmd) 
Error in View(sp) : X11 dataentry cannot be loaded
Calls: <Anonymous> ... withCallingHandlers -> withVisible -> eval -> eval -> View
Execution halted
```

Has anyone had this issue before?

The closest solution I could find was [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/254380/why-am-i-getting-an-invalid-active-developer-path-when-attempting-to-use-git-a), but I wanted to see if anyone had encountered the same issue or could confirm this would fix my problem before proceeding. I get real nervous messing around in my terminal without guidance...

Thank you in advance!

Comment: i'm assuming you did not try the solution in that question? install the command line tools while you are there

Comment: I did not. I will try adding the command line tools now.

Answer (score 0):

So I did need to install the command line tools, but I also needed to install [XQuartz](https://www.xquartz.org/) before I could use the knit function.
Now it works!